# Orchard Shape type ResizeMediaUrl not found Exception, MediaLibrary component not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I created a content type and a projection to view that content type, but when trying to access the projection I am getting the following exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Shape type ResizeMediaUrl not found

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Orchard.OrchardException: Shape type ResizeMediaUrl not found

Source Error: 


Line 3:  @{
Line 4:      ImagePart imagePart = Model.ContentPart;
Line 5:      var mediaPart = ((ContentItem)Model.ContentItem).As<MediaPart>();
Line 6:  }           
Line 7:  

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Staging\Themes\BodyLogicMD\Views\Parts.Image.Summary-Image.cshtml    Line: 5
```

The Media Library was disabled and enabled several times while testing for performance but now it and and all it's dependents modules are enabled. The site was also move from one location to another within the server, but the media folder and it's structure are in the same orchard structure.

When the media library module is disable the projections are displayed, but no picture associated with it is. When enable the above exception happens.

Please advise,

Thanks,

Alex.

Comment: Anything in app_data\logs?

Answer (score 1):

Here...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28671852/1814343

It's all about attaching the `Media part` to the your content type, and set its Stereotype to `Media`