# NullReference Exception when viewing Content page in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

In OrchardCMS v1.8.1.0, I receive the following error message when clicking on the Content link (/Admin/Contents/List) file name **Modules\Orchard.MediaLibrary\Views\Parts\Document.SummaryAdmin.cshtml**:

> **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
Source Error:

Line 3:  @{

Line 4:      DocumentPart documentPart = Model.ContentPart;
//The following line throws the exception
Line 5:      var mediaPart = ((ContentItem)Model.ContentItem).As<MediaPart>();

Line 6:  }

Line 7:
```

Stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Modules_Orchard_MediaLibrary_Views_Parts_Document_SummaryAdmin_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Modules\Orchard.MediaLibrary\Views\Parts\Document.SummaryAdmin.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +124
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +146
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:149
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:133
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:181
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:30
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +219
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.ContentZone(Object Display, Object Shape, TextWriter Output) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:274

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +211
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.PerformInvoke(DisplayContext displayContext, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object serviceInstance) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:65
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:30
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   ASP._Page_Core_Contents_Views_Content_SummaryAdmin_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Core\Contents\Views\Content.SummaryAdmin.cshtml:13
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +125
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +147
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:151
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:133
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:30
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.List(Object Display, TextWriter Output, IEnumerable`1 Items, String Tag, String Id, IEnumerable`1 Classes, IDictionary`2 Attributes, String ItemTag, IEnumerable`1 ItemClasses, IDictionary`2 ItemAttributes) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:687

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +211
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.PerformInvoke(DisplayContext displayContext, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object serviceInstance) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:65
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:185
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:94
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:30
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) +220
   ASP._Page_Core_Contents_Views_Admin_List_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Core\Contents\Views\Admin\List.cshtml:52
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +125
   Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.<>c__DisplayClass7.<FindView>b__5(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:60
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +380
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +109
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in z:\Builds\work\d1eb156ccc3cb14\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:159
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like somehow the MediaPart isn't attached to the Document content type, while it expects it to be.

Attach the Media part to the Document content type, and set its Stereotype to 'Media' (both can be done in the dashboard).